# How to get code coverage in jenkins using a separate test suite in Post Build step

Tags: maven, jenkins, automation, continuous-integration, jacoco

I've configured these in jenkins:
1. Developer code compilation using maven in BUILD step.
2. In Post Build step: I am launching my own automated code (written in testNG framework) using some shell script.

Now how do I get the code coverage by executing my automated tests. I am using jacoco also but Jacoco is giving the code coverage by executing the unit tests but not the code coverage by execution of my automated test suite. The unit test are launched by maven -  pom.xml and my test suite is executed in Post Build step. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not run the tests from the same POM file that you use to compile the code ?

Comment: I want to achieve the same but not sure how because my automation code is triggered by ant which in turn invokes a testNG.xml, any help would be appreciated.